# Include <iostream> => Successfull Build, but no .exe (Netbeans)

Tags: c++, netbeans, compilation, mingw, iostream

I'm trying to compile this C++ code, but no luck. Using MinGW and Netbeans 7.4. The code doesn't make sense because I erased everything down to a minimum for failure analysis. The problem seems to be the line "#include ". When it's there, the project builds, but no .exe is created. If it's not there, the project builds and runs just fine.

Any ideas ? Btw, I read those other 'can't include

main.cpp

```
    #include "xmessage.h"

    using namespace std;

    int main() {
        xmessage();
        return 0;
    }
```

xmessage.cpp

```
    #include <iostream>  // What's wrooong with you, <iostream> !?!?

    using namespace std;

    void xmessage ()  {
        int i = 1;
    }
```

xmessage.h

```
    #ifndef XMESSAGE_H
    #define XMESSAGE_H

    void xmessage ();

    #endif  /* XMESSAGE_H */
```

Also:

The files are .cpp, that's not it.

And if I remove the iostream file from the include folder 
C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++
the build fails. So that's definitely the file that is being used by the compiler.

Netbeans output:

```
"/C/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make.exe[1]: Entering directory `/c/Users/admin/Documents/NetBeansProjects   
/project125(HeaderFileMacros) - WIP'
"/C/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows 
/project125_headerfilemacros__-_wip.exe
make.exe[2]: Entering directory `/c/Users/admin/Documents/NetBeansProjects    
/project125(HeaderFileMacros) - WIP'
mkdir -p dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows
g++     -o dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/project125_headerfilemacros__-_wip build/Debug/MinGW-Windows
/main.o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/xmessage.o 
make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/admin/Documents/NetBeansProjects  
/project125(HeaderFileMacros) - WIP'
make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/admin/Documents/NetBeansProjects  
/project125(HeaderFileMacros) - WIP'
```

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 4s)

Comment: You have to include `xmessage.h` in `xmessage.cpp`. Are there any messages? Also make sure you have setup a C++ - not a C - project.

Comment: I changed xmessage.cpp to

    #include "xmessage.h"
    #include <iostream>  // What's wrooong with you, <iostream> !?!?

    using namespace std;

    void xmessage ()  {
        int i = 1;
    }

and I also changed the order of the two include lines. Result in both cases is the same as before.

Comment: Just do be sure I created a project with your code and compiled it. As you may expect: Everything works fine. So, can you please post the *build* output of Netbeans?

Comment: There's a main.o, xmessage.o and xmessage.o.d . I can't post the content since they are binary. I also don't see an option to post files. Sorry for being so helpless. Xmessage.o.d. contains this: build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/xmessage.o: xmessage.cpp xmessage.h

xmessage.h:

Comment: No, I mean the message output of netbeans. If you compile your program, netbeans writes messages to the *output*-window. But those object files show: compilation works.

Comment: Hmmm ... weird. Did you test your code with a fresh project? Create a new C/C++ Application project and compiled the code there? Did you change any settings of your current project?

Comment: At first, I copied an old application and changed it. But then it didn't work and because I suspected this could be the problem I also created a new C++ project. What I find weird is: This thing also builds without the #include "xmessage.h" command.

Comment: But does a new project work?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Now I see that my previous comment was confusing. They all build, but no .exe. If I "Run Project" netbeans gives me an error message that the executable is nowhere to be found which is true.

Comment: Did you check the settings of compiler, linker etc? Please make a test with a simple makefile (without IDE).

Comment: I do not know how makefiles work yet. But I will look that up und try it.

Comment: The problem was solved in another thread (do you call it that here?) I posted when I ran into a problem creating a simple makefile (because I wanted to follow your advice, but didn't know much about makefiles). The user RobKennedy suggested that it was an overeager filesystem monitor which was exactly what it was.  My Avast Antivir was in silent mode and it put every new .exe in quarantine without notifying me. How do I close this / highlight the solution ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avast Antivir was in silent mode and it put every new .exe in quarantine without notifying me. That's why the .exe was instantly deleted after its creation.